Autofilling Tkinter Widgets?
I want to autofill python tkinter widgets/entries with data from my SQL database. This is what I want to happen.
Upon initiation the gui pulls data from SQL and takes it and enters it into corresponding widget.
I.e SQL query pulls data from column "Student_age"
I want it to be put into an entry such as this:
self.student_age = tk.Entry(self, width=15)

I'm not quite sure how I would do this. I could not find any further documentation online

Entry widgets have .delete() and .insert() methods that allow you to modify their contents.

Use a dictionary to store the references of those entry widgets with the column names as keys.  Retrieve records as dictionary (if supported) from database, then you can fill corresponding entries using column names.

Thanks guys! I had thought there was some built-in module or something for something like this. I guess I'll have to do it the regular way

I'm not sure how to use SQL in Python, but I do know how the Tkinter part would be done.
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

entry = tk.Entry(window, width=15)

entry.pack()

# This is the function to retireve SQL Data
def getSQLData():
    return "John Smith"
    
entry.delete(0, tk.END)
entry.insert(0, getSQLData())

window.mainloop()

